# how to read a file in batches/parts/1000 lines at a time

Tags: c#, xml, filestream, streamreader, xmlreader

I am currently trying to make a method that can handle reading in large XML files. All i need is a method that would loading in say 1000 lines at a time or in small batches.

I have been looking at streamreaders, xmlreaders and filestreams, I have seen some mentions of just keeping the stream open while processing data to get what i need but i cant seem to get my head round it.

I have spent a long time checking the similar questions but can seem to find anything that will help me.

ps. first thought i was thinking of doing a for loop around the readline to a counter of 1000 but cant seem to figure out how to continue from that 1000 lines to reading another 1000 etc until the end of the file.

Comment: This is going to be very hard to do in batches. What if an XML element is split between two of the batches?

Comment: well that was one idea to read these files in was just listing my ideas to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My feeling is that his will require a custom XML reader implementation.

For example - if your structure looks something like:

```
root
    item
        stuff
    /item
    item
        stuff
    /item
    item
        stuff
    /item
    item
        stuff
    /item
/root
```

You'll have to write code that reads a number 'item' blocks (as many as yuo wish to process in a batch), and then converts them into a valid XML doc for further processing.

If, however, your XML doc is one massive sprawling entity - I don't think  there's any elegant way you can process it piece-meal.